# Can only access Ubuntu using "recovery mode" or "previous versions"

Tags: startup, plymouth

The main link to use Ubuntu takes me to a dark screen.
Is there anything I can do while in recovery mode to fix this? I currently cant access the internet once I upgraded to the 12.04LTS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like X isn't starting, in recovery mode you can try to update the drivers or in grub you can set it to use vesa (fall back mode) this will get you into the OS at the very least but it will be slow and not a permanent solution.

This video might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTmZYzaxR_k